# Modelling Asian eyes HELP!

Tags: modeling

I really need help modeling Asian, specifically Chinese eyes. I’ve been learning character modeling recently and I would say that I have a pretty solid grasp on almost everything except Asian eyelids. I can’t figure out a way to model the monolid on top and epicanthic fold on the inside corner while having clean topology and without my model ripping and tearing. Does anyone have any advice? I can’t find any tutorials covering this anywhere on the internet. I’m going for Lucy Liu eyes. Please help!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like something that you should either sculpt, or use more dense topology on.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've ever been able to do is to use one of the human modeling programs or blender addons like [Makehuman](http://www.makehumancommunity.org/) or [Manuel Bastioni Labs](http://www.manuelbastioni.com/) to approximate the shape I want and then replicate the topology into my own model.